# How can I get the connected hotspot BSSID/MAC Address in a React Native app?

Tags: react-native

I can easily do that using existing packages for Android, but I couldn't find any package that would do the same both on Android and iOS.

**Update (Feb-08, 2017):**

After waiting over two weeks and placing a bounty on the question which resulted in zero answers, I decided to implement a new package ([react-native-gateway-finder](https://github.com/ymuzikant/react-native-gateway-finder)) that returns the exact info I was looking for.
It is currently implemented for Android only and an iOS implementation is welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

After I did some search on google, got the result as below:

- [react-native-network-info](https://github.com/pusherman/react-native-network-info) works with both Android and iOS. But you might need to upgrade your react-native version to `0.48` or higher.
- [react-native-android-wifi](https://github.com/devstepbcn/react-native-android-wifi) works with Android platform.

If you only need some basic info, [NetInfo](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.48/netinfo.html) provided by react-native is a good choice.